# How do I determine if a GPU is available in FireMonkey in Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, gpu, firemonkey

I'm doing some image transitions in FireMonkey (FM2) which don't work on some low end machines, how do I determine (programatically) if there is a GPU present so that I can do something more mundane if there is no GPU?

Comment: How much cross-platform support do you need?

Comment: Are you aware which all the [applications built with FireMonkey require a GPU, accessible directly or through virtualization](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/FireMonkey_Platform_Prerequisites)?

Comment: Maybe you should instead write an app which checks the performance of some benchmark action, and if the time to execute it is too high, you warn the user (but continue anyways) that performance seems very poor, and disable the "extra stuff". Timing a transition and seeing if it achieves X fps, for example.

Comment: It's Windows only, so not cross platform at all.

Comment: @WarrenP The app doesn't work at all on low powered machines.

Comment: Perhaps you can detect the performance problem with some simple code, before you run your complex code.

Comment: @WarrenP It's not so much as a performance problem, in as much as it doesn't render at all.  I just want to be able to test for the presence of a GPU (which is presumably possible within the FireMonkey framework), if there is none I wont render the fancy effects.

Comment: @Alister as pointed by RRUZ, it looks like it will require a GPU even without the fancy effects. Did your application successfully runs on the target hardware without that fancy effects?

Comment: @RRUZ The machines in question do run FireMonkey apps.

Comment: It seems to me Embarcadero should add this check to Firemonkey. it's on their web page for requirements, it should be possible to check if a machine meets the minimum specs to run this application. "Sorry this application requires a modern 3D-capable video card to run", hopefully written in plain english (or other localized language) so users know that this application requires a GPU, although they won't actually know what a GPU is...  :-)

Comment: @WarrenP in many instances the GPU is not actually required, for instance it's not available in Remote Desktop situations - it's only when doing specific things that it is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be determined via the GlobalUseHWEffects﻿ global variable in FMX.Types.  If true the image transition effects will work.